# vue.js i used 'v-once' in 'v-for' statement,why can't find 'item'?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<div v-for="item in imControls.messages" >
    <p v-once>
        <span class="" v-if="item.type==3">{{item.name}}:</span>
        <span class="red" v-if="item.type==4">{{item.name}}:</span>
        <span class="blue" v-if="item.type==2">{{item.name}}:</span>
        <span class="grey" v-if="item.type==1">{{item.name}}:</span>
        <span v-html="item.text"></span>
    </p>
 </div>
```

`imControls.messages` exists, if I don't use `v-once` on `p` label, it's ok, but if I use `v-once`, it can't find item.

The error is

> 'vue.js:2574 [Vue warn]: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in root instance)
>
> vue.js:2217 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined'

Comment: Are you loading `imControls.messages` asynchronously?

Comment: yes,imControls.messages can  change ,but i want each item in imControls.messages  don't need change after  rendered.Because in item.text, it has some img label string, i don't want load img resource many times.

Answer (score 0):

`v-once` directive can be used in the `v-for` directly

```
<div v-for="item in imControls.messages" v-once>
    <span class="" v-if="item.type==3">{{item.name}}:</span>
    <span class="red" v-if="item.type==4">{{item.name}}:</span>
    <span class="blue" v-if="item.type==2">{{item.name}}:</span>
    <span class="grey" v-if="item.type==1">{{item.name}}:</span>
    <span v-html="item.text"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need v-once in v-for statement,because it is fixed in vue.js 2.0.8

## 4247 fix v-html resetting content even when content string stays the same